# An exception was raised while creating "MvcTranslator"; no instance returned

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, composer-php

I am try to run a ZF2 application while runnig getting an error "`An exception was raised while creating "MvcTranslator`"; no instance returned" after updating composer.

I have changed minimum requirement parameter from `"minimum-stability": "stable"` to `"minimum-stability": "dev"` in composer.json.

Here is my composer.json

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.zendframework.com/"
        }
    ],
    "homepage": "http://framework.zend.com/",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "zendframework/zendframework": "2.*",
        "doctrine/doctrine-orm-module": "*",
        "zendframework/zend-developer-tools": "dev-master",
        "webino/zf2nette-debug": "dev-master",
        "nitecon/zf2-db-session": "1.*",
    "zf-commons/zfc-user": "*",
        "nitecon/zfcuser-ldap": "dev-master",
    "zf-commons/zfc-rbac":"dev-master"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

Below is the stack error.

```
                try {
892:                $circularDependencyResolver[$depKey] = true;
893:                $instance = call_user_func($callable, $this, $cName, $rName);
894:                unset($circularDependencyResolver[$depKey]);
895:            } catch (Exception\ServiceNotFoundException $e) {
896:                unset($circularDependencyResolver[$depKey]);
897:                throw $e;
898:            } catch (\Exception $e) {
899:                unset($circularDependencyResolver[$depKey]);
900:                throw new Exception\ServiceNotCreatedException(
901:                    sprintf('An exception was raised while creating "%s"; no instance returned', $rName),
902:                    $e->getCode(),
903:                    $e
904:                );
```

Can any one please help me getting out of this, its been while i am googling.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think i have the best solution, but this avoid the error.

Create a service with the translator object.
Edit one of your modules, adding the service **MvcTranslator**. For example, i edited my *module/MyApplication/Module.php*

```
namespace MyApplication

use Zend\I18n\Translator\Translator;
/* Some other "use" */

class Module {

    /* Code of module */

    public function getServiceConfig() {
        return array(
            'factories' => array(
                'MvcTranslator' => function($service) {
                    return new Translator();
                },
                /* Other services */
            ),
        );
    }
```

This works for me because i am not using translation. If you need work with translation, check this:
http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.i18n.translating.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Zend Framework 2.2 or later.

Try this.

```
Comment out or remove 
  //use Zend\I18n\Translator\Translator;     // comment out for ZF 2.2.0
  //USE THIS for 2.2
 use Zend\Mvc\I18n\Translator;`         // comment in for ZF 2.2.0
```